# conftest verify is unexpectedly passing

Tags: open-policy-agent, conftest

Running conftest verify resulted in a pass even though the rule should have failed at `db.storage_encrypted != true`. What am I missing here?

```
# deny.rego
deny_unencrypted[msg] {
  db := input.resource.aws_db_instance[x]
  db.storage_encrypted != true # should fail here
  msg = sprintf("RDS `%v` has unencrypted storage", [x])
}

# deny_test.rego
test_unencrypted {
  cfg := parse_config("hcl2", `
    resource "aws_db_instance" "default" {
      storage_encrypted = true
    }
  `)

   deny_unencrypted with input as cfg
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `deny_unencrypted` rule creates a *set*, and even empty sets are "truthy", so this expression is going to be true regardless of input:

```
deny_unencrypted with input as cfg
```

What you probably want to do is something like:

```
count(deny_unencrypted) > 0 with input as cfg

# or 

count(deny_unencrypted) == 0 with input as cfg

# if you're looking to test that no violations happened
```

Or even take the expected message into account:

```
deny_unencrypted["RDS `default` has unencrypted storage"] with cfg as input
```

You'd need to set `storage_encrypted = false` in your mock data for that test to work though.

Comment: "The deny_unencrypted rule creates a set, and even empty sets are "truthy", so this expression is going to be true regardless of input:" Now this makes sense. Testing for the number of items in the set seems to be a much better practice to check for violation.